# How to get the address of memory location to which a pointer is pointing

Tags: c, pointers

```
 #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
        int i = 3;
        int* j = &i;
        printf("%u",j);
    }
```

The above code should print out the address (an unsigned integer) of memory block in which integer 3 is contained. But instead I am getting this error-
`error: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *'`.

I confirmed from various sources that:
1. `*j` refers to "value at address stored in j"
2. `&j` refers to address of memory block in which pointer j is stored.
3. j contains an unsigned int value which is the address of memory block at which j is pointing.

Comment: Not sure, but try using %d.

Comment: how did you conclude that address is unsigned int?

Comment: @identicon: treat a pointer as an int? Really?

Comment: @perreal conclude? i have learnt C from very basic. and it is indeed an unsigned integer.

Answer (score 5):

Your `%u` is incorrect. `j` is a pointer, so you should use `%p`. This change should do:

```
printf("%p", (void *)j);
```

Answer (score 2):

As you a trying to print out the address you need the `p` flags - see [printf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) manual page.

Hence the code should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i = 3;
    int* j = &i;
    printf("%p",(void *)j);
}
```

See [here](https://ideone.com/dpqtUe)